# Search multiple words separated by space in laravel 6 doesn't work

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've read several similar posts and I tried them, but still it doesn't work for my site.

When I search a word "think" the search result shows "I **think** this is it".
However, when I search "I think" the result is "0 match found".

So to achieve multiple words search, I did below:

Controller.php

```
$keyword = "I think"

$words = explode(' ', $keyword);

$data = Post::where(function ($query) use ($words) 
{
  foreach($words as $word){
     $query->where('example', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%');
  }
})->get();
```

However, result is same. "think" shows results. "I think" doesn't hit any results.

also debugged with `dd($data)`

```
// $keyword = "think"
"select * from `posts` where (`example` LIKE ?)"
// $keyword = "I think"
"select * from `posts` where (`example` LIKE ? and `example` LIKE ?)"
```

So what would be wrong? Thank you.

[Additonal info (Edited)]

```
$bindings = $query->getBindings();
dd($bindings);

// array:2 [▼
  0 => "%I%"
  1 => "%think%"
]
```

Comment: Could you also post your bindings output here? `$query->getBindings();`

Comment: @ITDesigns-eu I added.

Comment: I think your problem is starring at you now :) Your binding should look like `%I%`, `%think%`. So the problem is in your $keyword... Are you sure the whitespace between I and think is the same as in explode function?

Comment: Also, you don't need to break *I think*, `LIKE "%I think%"` should work fine

Comment: @ITDesigns-eu Thank you for your advice! So I checked `print_r($words);` then result is `Array ( [0] => I [1] => think ) ` so $keyword explode looks still working. Also without using explode, the search must be going to `LIKE "%I think%"` , however, still same result. It doesn't work. hmm...

Comment: can you debug `$word` in your `$query->where('example', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%');` statement?

Comment: @ITDesigns-eu I wrote `print_r($word);` in foreach, then it showed `Ithink`.

Comment: This is crazy... Are you sure there is nothing overriding the query in your model or later in the method? Your bindings are completely different!

Comment: @ITDesigns-eu You are correct. I changed `$query` to `$q` and checked binding again. then result is `array:2 [ 0 => "%I%" 1 => "%think%" ]` So, it looks working properly. however, result is still "0 match found".

Comment: Could you please post the output of `$data = Post::where(function ($query) use ($words) 
{
  foreach($words as $word){
     $query->where('example', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%');
  }
});` `$data->toSql()`, `$data->getBindings()`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Laravel scout for this. But alternatively, to do a fuzzy text search in sql.
Or... assuming we don't use MYSQL match features, and we were to use a laravel eloquent.
1) Split the string. 
2) use query builder.

```
$words = explode(' ', $searchString);
$results = Post::where(($q) use ($words) {
   $firstWord = array_shift($words);
   $q->where('example', $firstCase);
    foreach($words as $word) {
      $q->orWhere('example', $word);
   }
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

It was my bad.
On my blade.php, there was a line

```
@if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/",$keyword))
```

this regex didn't have space, that's why it didn't work.
so just changed to:

```
@if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z ]*$/",$keyword))
```

then totally it worked.

Thank you for helping teachers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = User::where(function ($query) use($userSearch) {
        $searchWords = explode(' ', $userSearch);
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchWords[0].'%');
        for($i=1;$i<count($searchWords);$i++) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchWords[$i].'%');
        }
    })->get();
```